# MySQL Database Structure for Club and Staff members Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to develop a new website for event management system.

I want everyone to sign up as a simple user only and then if they chose to run event user can then create an Organisation and create events.

Every club will have lots of staff members who should then be able to log in and make changes into the event. Like accounting,event set up and entries, Refunds etc.

So I have created few roles like following

```
clubOwner :- All permission
eventManager :- Tier 1
treasurer :- Tier 2
```

Now how should I structure staff roles and permission table so that if in future creator of the `club` leaves that organisation he/she can easily nominate someone else `clubOwner`.

It is also the case that one `eventManager` handles events for different clubs or they can also run events under own Organisation name.

So far I have come up with following structure

```
clubs
=========
id | clubName | clubOwner

club_staff
id | clubId | accountId | roleId

club_roles
id | name 

club_role_permission
id | roleId | permissionId

club_role_permission_details
id| name |
```

I am not sure if this will solve both of my problem of `clubOwner` easily nominating other user and same user with different roles in different clubs.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Though this topic is subjective to many developers, I believe you are in the right track.

`Permissions` - normally corresponds to smallest unit of actions like View Club Staff, Add Club Staff, Remove Club Staff and so on. Normal club staff can *view* other staff within their club, but cannot *add* or *remove* club members.

`Roles` - are group of `Permissions` that are related to each other. `ClubManagerRole` for example must have all the permissions related to managing the club, while `ClubStaffRole` can only *view* members for example.

`Users` - are your users, that's all.

`UserRoles` - a junction table which has many-to-many relationship between `Users` and `Roles`. In other words, a *user* can have **many** roles, and a certain *role* can be assigned to **many** users. Just like how there are many **Club Managers** but maybe some of them can also be **Other Managers**.

`Clubs` - are your clubs.

`ClubUsers` (or staff) - are the users of a club. If a certain *user* is allowed to be a staff of one club only, one-to-many will be a fit choice. Otherwise, you can go with a junction table again for many-to-many relationship which will allow for users being assigned to many clubs.

The nomenclatures again, are also subjective. You can search for `Database practices/normalization` to get a basic a idea on how one can come up with a good schema.